Is there any way to use Associated Function of a trait in Rust?
I was experimenting with associated functions inside a trait's implementation, in order to use the trait's original implementation of the function. But I can't find a way to do that. My experimentation code :
pub trait T1 {
    // note: trait items always share the visibility of their methods.
    fn new() -> String {
        return String::new();
    }
}

pub enum X_type {
    String,
}

struct T1_1 {
    buddy: String,
}

impl T1 for T1_1 {}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", <dyn T1 as T1>::new());
}

Link to the playground.
I have tried tweaking the code here and there to see if T1::new() can be used, but it does not seem possible.

If you try T1::new() the compiler will actually tell you what to do:
error[E0790]: cannot call associated function on trait without specifying the corresponding `impl` type
  --> src/main.rs:19:20
   |
3  | /     fn new() -> String {
4  | |         return String::new();
5  | |     }
   | |_____- `T1::new` defined here
...
19 |       println!("{}", T1::new());
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^ cannot call associated function of trait
   |
help: use the fully-qualified path to the only available implementation
   |
19 |     println!("{}", <T1_1 as T1>::new());
   |                    ++++++++   +

This is because there can be different implementation for T1::new() for each type which implements this trait, so you should specify which implementation you want.

Thanks for the answer, But my intention is to use the implementation of the trait instead of using an implementer type 's implementation.

@Divyansh you cannot do that. Traits should be though of as interfaces, not as implementation. They don't have any code associated with them. The code you wrote provides a default implementation for any actual implementation of the trait.

Thanks @jthulhu. Got it now. Default Implementation for any actual one.
